# Get value for a FlatLaf theme

Tags: java, swing, flatlaf

I have a little problem getting certain values ​​contained in the themes of flatlaf, I'll give you an example, the value of "@accentBase2Color" return null and i don't understand why because the theme contain this key (sry for my bad english).

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedLookAndFeelException {
    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(flatLaf);
    
    Color obj = UIManager.getColor("@accentBaseColor");
    
    System.out.println(obj);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@accentBase2Color exist only in the theme file so it is unreachable from the UIManager.
You can use the following code to reach every UIManager key/color attribut, I think the color you want to find is stored in "Object.pink" or "Object.purple" for exemple.

```
private static void DrawGizmos(String search) {

    UIDefaults defaults = UIManager.getDefaults();
    System.out.println(defaults.size() + " properties defined !");
    Map<String, Color> mapString = new HashMap<>();
    for (Enumeration<Object> e = defaults.keys(); e.hasMoreElements();) {
        Object key = e.nextElement();

        if (key.toString().toUpperCase().contains(search.toUpperCase())) {
            if (defaults.get(key) instanceof Color) {
                mapString.put(key.toString(), (Color) defaults.get(key));
            }
        }
    }

    JPanel jPanel = new JPanel();

    for (Map.Entry<String, Color> entry:mapString.entrySet()){
        JButton btn = new JButton(entry.getKey() + " |-| " + entry.getValue().toString());
        btn.setBackground(entry.getValue());
        jPanel.add(btn);
    }

    JFrame p = new JFrame("UIManager");
    jPanel.setLayout(new VerticalLayout());
    p.add(new JScrollPane(jPanel));
    p.setVisible(true);
    p.setSize(400, 500);
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(new FlatCarbonIJTheme());
    } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    DrawGizmos("Objects");
}
```